# Bytebuddy agent for REST services

Tags: byte-buddy

I want to setup instrumentation for bytebuddy for my REST services. Jax-rs services is running on remote host. I want to run a separate process on some other machine which will attach a java agent to the running service and should do the following.

1. Print something whenever it enters an actual rest method.
2. Send some other response like 401,402 .... without hitting REST service
3. Trace flow on each method enter and exit so as to come up with automatic flow chart based on a code flow for any user activity

I am not sure how to setup bytebuddy for the above use cases. Any pointers please ...

Comment: This is a very broad question. Basically, you want to implement tracing. Have a look at open source solutions who already achieve this such as Stagemonitor to give you an overview.

Comment: I don’t think stagemonitor will help to build sequence diagram based on the call tracing.